# Problem with routes in hosted web application (VUE.JS + NET CORE 3.1)

Tags: vue.js, routes, web-hosting, asp.net-core-3.1

**EDIT:**

Finally and after several days trying to solve the problem with Axios BaseURL, it seems that the reason for the 404 error in my hosted app must be that an application created with VUE.JS + NET.CORE 3.1 has problems establishing the routes (it works perfectly on localhost). I have changed the main title of the question and expose my startup.cs file if someone observes something strange in it, I will be grateful.

[image: screen shot of error]

[image]

Startup.cs:

```cs
    public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                //Configuration = configuration;
                Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()                        
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                            .Build();
            }        
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration: options => { options.RootPath = "/";});
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddHostedService<ApplicationPartsLogger>();            
                services.AddDbContext<DbContextSistema>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Conexion"))                
                    );
                services.AddCors(options => {
                    options.AddPolicy("Todos",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").WithHeaders("*").WithMethods("*").SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
                });
                services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
                services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],                        
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                        };
                    });            
            }
            
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {                        
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler();                
                }            
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
                loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/Log-{Date}.txt");            
                app.UseCors("Todos");
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                    { 
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name:"default",pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id}");                
                    });
                app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
                 {
                     builder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                     endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home"));
                 });
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's unknown why you get 404. There should be no room for guessing. You can clearly see requests in dev tools, check network tab. They either have correct urls, or not. If they do, the problem is on back end, it's front end otherwise.

Comment: You are right Estus, it may be the back end, I had thought it could come from the endpoints maybe. How can I try it?

Comment: For starters, you need to check network tab in dev tools, as said above. Then the problem could be isolated to either front or back end

Comment: I have edited my question to include a pair of screenshot, can you give me the key to determine if I need isolated one or other? Thanks

Comment: It's unknown what the correct url is expected to be. It's unknown what the response is. It could be 404 caused by incorrect url, or it could be api response because you try to log in as nonexistent user - most likely the first, but any way.

Comment: The app works fine on localhost with the same database so the routes are correct and the user is correct too. I have also tested it with free authentication requirements and the result is the same. The only thing that has changed is the axios BaseUrl, that is why I suspect that the url of the subdomain may be masked or there is some proxy system involved.

Answer (score 0):

give the `baseURL` if you are in local or hosting and take the every route in **router.js**  take the path page you want to access it and
put it like this

**baseURL/your page path**